# My page allows only one operation at a time

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp

I'm currently on XAMPP and Mac OSX and I have the following scenario and problem.

Let's pretend I have two VirtualHosts

`a.dev` and `b.dev`

a.dev has a cronjob that takes some time. Now, while doing that I want to develop further on other sites, but the cronjob on a.dev has blocked everything and I can't access anything on the page anymore. However, `b.dev` works without problems, so it seems that there is only a problem with the hosts.

Or could it be the database that makes problems? That it somehow locks tables? But then I wouldn't be able to access the phpmyadmin page of the database, right?

Comment: If you stop the cron job, does a.dev work ?

Comment: Yes. a.dev works without problems all the time, but as soon as I start another job that takes some more time it blocks the rest of the webpage.

Comment: What is that cron job doing?

Answer (score 1):

Your cron job is probably eating all the resources allocated for the php script on `a.dev`. You need to raise the limits in your `php.ini` or improve the script:

- you delete the variables you don't need anymore to free the memory
- if your script contains a loop, you can use `sleep()` after each loop to limit the CPU usage